# How to prevent decoding of @PathVariable value by default in springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a Spring-Boot  application running on a Tomcat . Within it, i have a RestController with pathvariable.
The pathvariable is decoded by default for eg if I give http://localhost:8080/v1/test/test2/%26, the path variable is automatically decoded as & , I need to disable this autodecoding.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/v1/test/test2//{pathVariable:.+}", method = RequestMethod.GET,produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
     public String getV2LocationByName(
                                      @PathVariable
                                      String cityName,
                                      @RequestParam(value = LANGUAGE, defaultValue = US_ENGLISH_LOCALE) String language,
                                      HttpServletRequest request) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
--------------
---------------
}
```

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but do you send *not* encoded parameters to this API?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to encode it from the UTF-8

```
String encodedParam = URLEncoder.encode(test, "UTF-8");
```

You can find more details [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html)